# Javascript String indexOf not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I must be missing something .. not sure why my JavaScript is failing or not working

```
var discount = 10;
var newTemp;

if (discount != null) {
    if (discount.indexOf("%") > -1) {
        newTemp = discount.substring(0, 2) + '%';
    } else {
        newTemp = discount;
    }
 } //end of outer if
```

Above script works when discount = "10.0%"
But fails when discount = 10

maynot be best way, but all I am trying to do is if discount value contains % sign then setting newTemp variable with new value. Else just keep it as is.

Any idea, why control fails when discount value is = 10

Comment: It fails how? What errors do you see?

Comment: I do not see any error. I did quick debug by placing alert and it stops at if (discount.indexOf("%") > -1) if the value of discount=10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because "10%" is a string, therefore it has a `indexOf` method, and 10 is probably an integer or number.

Try `discount.toString().indexOf('%')`

Comment: I think you are right, it is treating 10 as number, however i tried your .toString() solution but did not work

Comment: it is too hard to help you with the information you provide. You should consider improving your debugging process - http://getfirebug.com/javascript

Comment: thank you for your feedback, i changed a logic little bit but understood overall issue was because of variable value is treated as number.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not appending the '%' in the else branch.

```
var newTemp;
if (discount != null) {
    if (discount.indexOf("%") > -1) {
        newTemp = discount.substring(0, 2);
    } else {
        newTemp = discount;
    }
 } //end of outer if
 newTemp += '%';
```

also as Hugo said, the number 10 does not have the `indexOf` method, which is a string method.

Comment: `.toString()` was the key for me!